# javax.el - Implementação da Glassfish

Tags: api, maven, glassfish

Há uma API da JSR-000341(Expression Language - EL) na versão 3.0.0.

Dependência Maven da API javax.el:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Mas quanto a implementação eu vou usar a da glassfish, mas existe as seguintes implementações:

Do **org.glassfish** (última versão):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

E **org.glassfish.web** (última versão):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Tem alguma diferença entre a implementação da **org.glassfish** e **org.glassfish.web**, desconsiderando a versão das duas implementações?

Comment: Preciso investigar melhor para te dar uma resposta, mas o [site da UEL](https://uel.java.net/download.html) recomenda o uso do artefato em `org.glassfish.web`.

Comment: Por outro lado [no site da JSR](https://java.net/projects/el-spec/downloads) está sendo recomendado a implementação `org.glassfish.javax.el`. Isso tem cara de RI que mudou com o tempo.

Comment: RI? Não sei o que significa. Mas chutando, você quer dizer que os desenvolvedores da implementação javax.el da glassfish passaram a colocar a implementação no **org.glassfish** ao invés da **org.glassfish.web**?

Comment: RI = Implementação de Referência (da especificação). E sim, foi isso mesmo. Elaborei o assunto e tentei explicar cada nuncia na resposta. Se tiver alguma dúvida me avise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Para aplicações web típicas

**Utilize a implementação disponível no servidor de aplicação.**

Se você está desenvolvendo uma aplicação web para ser publicada no GlassFish (ou qualquer outro servidor de aplicação), você **não** precisa de uma implementação da EL, apenas da API (em escopo `provided`). O próprio GlassFish irá disponibilizar a implementação:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Na prática porém dificilmente incluímos uma dependência para essa API diretamente, geralmente trabalhamos em um nível de granularidade maior. Aplicações web são consumidoras das principais APIS do Java EE (incluindo *Servlets*, JSP, JSF, *Expression Language*, etc):

```
<dependency>  
   <groupId>javax</groupId>    
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId> <!-- Ou javaee-api se realmente precisar -->   
    <version>7.0</version>  
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Não se esqueça também das APIS *[endorsed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/)*, ou seja, atualizações para APIs do *JDK* necessárias para o *container* (especialmente relevantes para *JAXB*, *JAX-WS*, etc):

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Demais plugins -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*Et voilà*:

```
<!-- Lambda dentro de uma EL, não fica mais legal que isso --> 
<h1>Hello World! ${((x, y) -> x + y)(3, 4)}</h1>
```

É basicamente isso que o [arquétipo webapp-javaee7](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/java_ee_7_maven_archetype) faz.

---

## Disponibilizando a API fora do *App Server*

Dito isso, sua pergunta faz sentido caso você precise disponibilizar uma implementação de EL junto com sua aplicação. Por exemplo, se você está utilizando um *embedded container* e quer disponibilizar a implementação de referência (RI) da *Expression Language*.

### [EL 3.0](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=341) / [Java EE 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html)

Para a versão 3.0 da EL utilize a seguinte combinação de dependências:

```
<!-- API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>                
</dependency>
<!-- Implementação -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

### [EL 2.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/) / [Java EE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee6technologies-1955512.html)

O GlassFish também mantém [um projeto](https://uel.java.net/) com versões *standalone* da EL 2.2.x:

```
<!-- API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Implementação -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Na época do [Tomcat 6](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) / [Jetty 6](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html) esse tipo de arranjo era comum para habilitar a EL 2.2 ([eis um tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/HowToEnableEl22)). Hoje em dia ambos os *containers* (Tomcat 8 / Jetty 9.1) já disponibilizam EL 3.0.

---

Por que existem pacotes diferentes? Pois os desenvolvedores do GlassFish mudaram a convenção para nomes de grupos e artefatos do maven.

- Na versão 3.x do GlassFish os artefatos relacionados com desenvolvimento web eram agrupados em [`org.glassfish.web`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web).
- Na versão 4.x os artefatos foram reagrupados em [`org.glassfish`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish) (ou seja, você encontrará versões recentes das implementações nesse grupo). Os nomes dos artefatos também foram repensados para coincidir com o pacote raiz do serviço que implementam.

Coincidentemente a [JSR 341](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=341) (EL 3.0) foi a primeira especificação separada da *Expression Language*. A versão 2.2 da API fazia parte da [JSR 245](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/) (*JavaServer Pages*).

Comment: Anthony, obrigado pelo interesse em minha pergunta e obrigado por essa resposta, você respondeu muito claramente a minha pergunta e ainda me ensinou algumas coisas muito úteis à respeito das dependências do maven. Eu gostaria que você me dissesse mais uma coisa, onde nas documentações dos servidores de aplicação posso consultar quais implementações eles fornecem, pois preciso saber se o tomcat 8 atende a todas as necessidades durante o desenvolvimento de aplicações web em java.

Comment: Um servidor de aplicação de fato (como GlassFish, JBoss, Weblogic, Websphere, etc) implementa, e é comumente certificado contra uma versão do Java EE. Nesse caso ele deve disponibilizar ao menos [todas as tecnologias](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) da versão do Java EE que implementa. O Tomcat por outro lado não é um servidor de aplicação, é apenas um *cotainer* para Servlets e JSP; você encontra as APIs implementadas [nessa página](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Specifications) (veja também a [tabela de versões](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)).

Comment: Hmm entendi, qualquer servidor de aplicação que esteja de acordo com o Java EE fornecerá alguma implementação de todas as suas especificações. Assim só preciso me preocupar em usar as APIs da Java EE como **provided** no Maven durante o desenvolvimento.